# What does the estimate column tell us in the summary function?

Tags: r

Here is my code

```
# create a model from the training data comparing the TargetField to the others
lm.fit <- lm(TargetField ~ .,train) 

# output a summary of the model
summary(lm.fit)
```

The output is something like

[image: summary output]

My question is, What does the `Estimate` column in the output tell us?

I tried typing

```
? summary.lm
```

in the console panel of RStudio but I do not see "Estimate" mentioned.

Comment: The short answer that these are the estimates of the coefficients. The long answer is that this not really a programming question in my opinion. You may find this introduction to linear models helpful: https://ucdavis-bioinformatics-training.github.io/2019-March-Bioinformatics-Prerequisites/thursday/linear_models.html

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49939/interpreting-summary-function-for-lm-model-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the estimate of the regression coefficients. `(Intercept)` stands for B0 while the other rows represent B1, B2 etc.